# Continuously rasterize changes the position of a line

Tags: after-effects, effects

I'm editing an incredibly complex template I've bought. I want to zoom in deeply on a line in the composition. Now this line will turn into a blurry mess without 'continuously rasterize' turned on.

So I have to use that feature. When I turn it on, the line changes position for no apparent reason.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Could it be that the line has an anchor point that disagrees with the rest of the composition?  Or could it be that the continuously-rasterize feature introduces a non-zero anchor point at some point?  You could check the value of the anchor point after the malignant operation.